# global name 're' is not defined

Tags: python, regex, mincemeat

I am new to python and working on a map reduce problem with mincemeat. I am getting the following error while running the mincemeat script.

```
$python mincemeat.py -p changeme localhost
error: uncaptured python exception, closing channel <__main__.Client connected at 0x923fdcc> 
(<type 'exceptions.NameError'>:global name 're' is not defined
 [/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|read|79]
 [/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py|handle_read_event|438] 
 [/usr/lib/python2.7/asynchat.py|handle_read|140]
 [mincemeat.py|found_terminator|96]
 [mincemeat.py|process_command|194]
 [mincemeat.py|call_mapfn|170]
 [raw1.py|mapfn|43])
```

My code rests in raw1.py script which is given in the above stacktrace  as `[raw1.py|mapfn|43]`.

```
import re
import mincemeat

# ...

allStopWords = {'about':1, 'above':1, 'after':1, 'again':1}

def mapfn(fname, fcont):
    # ...
    for item in tList[1].split():
        word = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', item).lower().strip()        # ERROR
        if (word not in allStopWords) and (len(word) > 1):
            # ....
```

I have already imported `re` in raw1.py. The error doesn't appear if I import `re` in mincemeat.py.

Comment: hurray, happy to see a fellow student from the big data course at coursera.

Answer (score 13):

You need to have the import statement in `mapfn` itself. `mapfn` gets executed in a different python process, so it doesn't have access to the original context (including imports) in which it was declared.

Comment: Thanks for mincemeat! It is a great tool. I was wondering since this question may be a common occurrence, you could mention this in your github wiki for mincemeat?

Answer (score 4):

"Global" variables in python are actually scoped to the module/file they're bound in; you do need to import them in every file that uses them.

A module name is just a variable like anything else.

Comment: You can see that Satyajit _does_ import `re` in the same file where it's used. Do to the way mincemeat works though, mapfn ends up executing in a context where it doesn't have access to the original imports.

Comment: @MichaelFairley: mincemeat.py is a separate file with no import.

Comment: mincemeat.py is a library that is being used that has no dependency on `re`. However, even though `mapfn` is defined in raw1.py, it ends up getting executed inside of a different python process in the context of mincemeat.py. Rather than modifying the library itself, the `import` can (and should) be added to `mapfn`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already answered this question. If you use re in mincemeat.py, you'll need to import re there as well.