# Unable to import re across several modules

Tags: python, import, nameerror

I am trying to split up my module into several modules such that each module only contains one class.

`ClassA` is my superclass in `file1.py`, `ClassB` is located in `file2.py` and inherits from `ClassA` and `ClassC` in `file3.py`, and `file4.py` contains `ClassD`, which inherits from `ClassB`, and `__main__`.

When I run `file4.py` I get the following traceback:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\file4.py in <module>()
   1016     t0 = time.time()
   1017     # Initialize dataframe object to save/export at the end of ClassD.
-> 1018     myData = ClassA(dataframe)
   1019
   1020     # Initialize ClassC objects.

C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\file1.py in __init__(self, dataframe)
     24                 self.df.rename(columns = {'%s'%header:'GTIN1'}, inplace = True)
     25             if re.search(".MPN", headerID):
---> 26                 header = headerID
     27                 self.df.rename(columns = {'%s'%header:'MPN'}, inplace = True)
     28

NameError: global name 're' is not defined
```

I have tried `import re` in both `ClassA`'s `__init__` and in the first line of `file1.py` after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725024/global-name-re-is-not-defined). Each file also imports the classes from the other modules in the directory. I have also tried copying `re.pyc` to the directory. Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/9743339) the solution? I tried adding the current directory to `sys.path` in each module, but that did not work either.

### Update

Below is the code mentioned in the comments that is still returning the NameError.

```
import re as re, pandas as pd

from file2 import ClassB as ClassB
from file3 import ClassC as ClassC # ClassC contains static methods that use re
from file4 import ClassD as ClassD

class ClassA(object):
    """Converts dataframe from unicode string objects to Python
    string objects, renames column headers.
    """

    def __init__(self, dataframe): # dataframe is defined in file4.py in __main__
        super(ClassA, self).__init__()
        self.df = dataframe.replace({r'[^\x00-\x7F]+':''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
        self.df = dataframe.applymap(str)

    # I commented out the following and still receive the NameError.
    # for headerID in self.df.columns:
        # if ('UPC' or 'GTIN1' or 'GTIN' or 'EAN') in headerID:
           # header = headerID
           # self.df.rename(columns = {'%s'%header:'GTIN1'}, inplace = True)
        # if re.search(".MPN", headerID):
            # header = headerID
            # self.df.rename(columns = {'%s'%header:'MPN'}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: You should `import re` at the beginning of the module, not in `__init__` of the class.

Comment: I have already tried that. I also put it in the directory's `__init__.py` to be safe.

Comment: Don't put it in `__init__.py`. Put it in the file in which you are calling `re.search`. Put it in every file in which you are referencing `re`, otherwise you'll have the error `'re' is not defined`. If you do that, you will not have that error any more.

Comment: I removed the import call from `__init__.py` and placed it at the top of every module using `re`. I am still getting the same error. Interestingly enough, when I comment out that portion of the code, the error still occurs. I also tried [Michael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12756257/9743339) and put the import statement into every class method, but nothing changed.

Comment: Well then show the code which has the import and still has the same error.